# FullCalendar 上のスケジュールイベントが F5 キーでの再読込で消える

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

[FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) について教えてください。

いくつかのサイトを参考にしてセットアップをしました。

（参考サイト）[jQueryのFullCalendarが素敵](http://rossy-dev.blogspot.jp/2010/04/jqueryfullcalendar.html)

予定を新規登録したりドラッグしてずらしたりしても、<kbd>F5</kbd>で再読込を行うと元に戻ってしまい、スケジュール登録前に戻ってしまいます。[公式のデモ](http://fullcalendar.io/)もドラッグして予定をずらしても<kbd>F5</kbd>で再読込すると元に戻ってしまいますよね？

これは、登録したスケジュールがサーバサイドに保存できていないためではと考えているのですが、サーバサイドに保存し、複数人でイベントを共有するような使い方をするためにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

[fullcalendar_engine](https://rubygems.org/gems/fullcalendar_engine) というRails のバックエンドはあるようです。( [デモ](http://vinsol.com/fullcalendar-demo), [github](https://github.com/vinsol/fullcalendar_rails) )